tailwind width screen always shown horizontall scrollbar



i try to learn styling with tailwind css within vite react but the provlem is the bottom scrollbar always shown up if i use width-screen on the css is it a bug or something?
heres my code
import React from 'react'
function Headers() {
return (

Headers part
Headers part
Headers part
Headers part
Headers part
Headers part

)
}
export default Headers

have you removed default margin applied to the body?

I did but still same i try to delete the entier css to see if its work but nothing , it still there

even if you remove the entire css, there are styles applied by the browser's user agent styles which you will need to override.
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/what-is-setting-an-8px-margin-on-my-page/309002#:~:text=The%20body%20element%20generally%20has,html%20element%20instead%20of%20body.

body {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
display: flex;
place-items: center;
min-width: 320px;
min-height: 100vh;
}
i already override it in the rroot body but still same
